# Error - int 'counter' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

```
\main112.cpp    In function 'int main()':
63  36  \main112.cpp    [Error] 'counter' was not declared in this scope
28               \Makefile.win  recipe for target 'main112.o' failed
```

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct Person
{
    string name;
    string race;
    int weight;

    void write();
    void show();
    void check();
};

void Person::show()
{
    cout<<"ÔÈÎ: "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"Íîìåð ðåéñà: "<<race<<endl;
    cout<<"Âåñ áàãàæà: "<<weight<<endl;
}

void Person::write()
{
    cout<<"Ââåäèòå ÔÈÎ: ";
    getline(cin,name);
    cout<<"Ââåäèòå íîìåð ðåéñà: ";
    getline(cin,race);
    cout<<"Ââåäèòå âåñ áàãàæà: ";
    cin>>weight;
    cin.ignore();
}

void Person::check()
{
    int counter = 0;
    if(weight>10)
    {
        counter++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    setlocale(0, "Russian");


    Person* persons=new Person[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        persons[i].write();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        persons[i].show();
        persons[i].check();
    }
    cout<<"Ñ áàãàæîì áîëüøå 10 êã: "<<counter<<" ÷åëîâåê"<<endl;

    delete[] persons;
    return 0;
}
```

Program that works the way its coded and should work, without this problem

Homework:

Write a program for processing passenger information. Information includes: 
1) Full name of the passenger.
2) Flight number. 
3) Luggage weight 
The program should allow the user to: 
1) Read data from the keyboard and display it. 
2) Calculate the number of passengers with the weight of baggage which is more than 10 kg

Comment: The error message is correct. The variable `counter` only exists inside the function `Person::check()` It is not usable anywhere else.

Comment: How can i fix it considering what i want from future program?

Comment: Your `counter` is created with the value zero each time you all `check()`, it's incremented if `weight>10` and then ceases to exist without ever being used at the end of the function call.

Comment: Why would `counter` be a class member? `Person` doesn't care about the count, only `main` does. My pitch a free function that tests and returns `bool` and let `main` keep count.

Comment: @user4581301 what is the counter counting?  How many people have wight over 10?

Comment: @Ayxan, yes, but the function is an abstraction. The counter would be implemented every time `check` returns `true`. `main` has no need to care what produces true.

Comment: This looks like a good place to use std::count_if. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count_if/

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you're defining counter in the scope of the function `Person::check()`.
Every time you run the `check` function a new variable called counter is created set to be the value 0. Then once it's through running that function it ceases to exist.

A quick and dirty way of fixing this would be declaring counter as a global variable.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int counter = 0;

struct Person
{
    string name;
    string race;
    int weight;

    void write();
    void show();
    void check();
};

void Person::show()
{
    cout<<"ÔÈÎ: "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"Íîìåð ðåéñà: "<<race<<endl;
    cout<<"Âåñ áàãàæà: "<<weight<<endl;
}

void Person::write()
{
    cout<<"Ââåäèòå ÔÈÎ: ";
    getline(cin,name);
    cout<<"Ââåäèòå íîìåð ðåéñà: ";
    getline(cin,race);
    cout<<"Ââåäèòå âåñ áàãàæà: ";
    cin>>weight;
    cin.ignore();
}

void Person::check()
{
    if(weight>10)
    {
        counter++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    setlocale(0, "Russian");


    Person* persons=new Person[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        persons[i].write();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        persons[i].show();
        persons[i].check();
    }
    cout<<"Ñ áàãàæîì áîëüøå 10 êã: "<<counter<<" ÷åëîâåê"<<endl;

    delete[] persons;
    return 0;
}
```

A better way would be defining counter as a member variable of your struct then you can get the value of each of the person objects' counter variable at anytime after declaring the object.

Comment: Usage of [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad) isn't really wise advice.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: See the linked Q&A. There are more to find. Basically it clutters your program and makes all of the parts harder to maintain. That's the whole point why c++ introduced encapsulation of data into classes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I agree that using global variables is bad advice, but it is the simplest way of getting what Favoras wants.

Comment: Which means the _simplest way_ isn't necessarily _the best_. I think we should always give _the best possible_ answers, to be as most useful for future research, and not just help the OP with their specific problem in short terms.

Comment: almost as simple would be to declare  `counter` as `static` and make `check` return its value. Actually it is cheating, because then `counter` can still be considered as a global variable by purists

Answer (score 1):

Familiarize yourself with the [concept of scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).

Because its scope is the function `Person::check`, `counter` is only visible within the bounds of `Person::check`. No other parts of the program are allowed to interact with it.

Suggested solution:

Change `Person::check` (and its declaration) to return a boolean. Example:

```
bool Person::check() const 
{
    return weight>10;
}
```

The method is declared `const` to promise that this function will not change the object. This is done to prevent errors and allow a function that should not change the object to be used on a constant `Person`. This can prevent subtle errors from creeping into the code.

Now a user can `check` a `Person`s baggage weight and do with the result of `check` whatever they want. In the case of `main`, it wants to keep a count. There is no reason for anyone but `main` to know what it does, so `counter` should be scoped by `main`.  eg:

```
int main()
{
   ...


    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        persons[i].show();
        if (persons[i].check()) 
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Ñ áàãàæîì áîëüøå 10 êã: "<<counter<<" ÷åëîâåê"<<endl;
    ...
}
```

Side note: There doesn't seem to be a need for `persons` to be dynamically allocated. Consider replacing

```
Person* persons=new Person[4];
```

with

```
Person persons[4];
```

and removing

```
delete[] persons;
```

If you are dynamically allocating in preparation for a variable number of `Person`s, [prefer to use `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

```
std::vector<Person> persons;
```

and `push_back` or `emplace_back` `Person`s as they are introduced.

Comment: I edited my code and now it give me this:

[Warning] non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
[Error] prototype for 'bool Person::check() const' does not match any in class [Error] candidate is: bool Person::check()


 void write();
 void show();
 bool check();

bool Person::check() const
{
 return weight>10;
}

Comment: @Favoras in the class definition, `bool check();` would have to be `bool check() const`. I am unsure how you get the first error message.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you fix it. Declare `counter` in `main`, make `check` return `bool`, and count the number of times it returns `false`. This encapsulates counter and it makes more sense for `check` to actually return a Boolean value. Here's what the body of `for` loop should do:

```
if (!persons[i].check())
  ++counter
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct, because there is no `counter` in `main`. You only declare `counter` here:

```
void Person::check()
{
    int counter = 0;
    if(weight>10)
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

and its scope is limited to that method. Actually each time the function is called you get a new `counter` which gets initialized to `0`.

If instead you make `counter` a member you can keep its value across multiple calls to the method:

```
class Person() {
    public:
    int counter = 0;
    int check() {
        if (weight > 10) ++counter;
    }
    // ...other stuff left out
};
```

I also changed the method to return the value of the counter (otherwise you would have to write a getter or some means to get its value).